# Select an image from the gallery and encrypt the data to it

Tags: android, jquery, android-layout, encryption, steganography

I have an xml layout in which there's a button and a text field. I fill in some message in the text field. Now when i click on the button i need to access the gallery and select an image. How to do get the message encrypted into this image and save it to my gallery again? Also what all types of encryption can be done on this image like AES

The function Selimg() is called by a button and when i click it, it should open the gallery for me to select an image. That image should be stored in 'thumbnail'. So that i can further encrypt it. This is my code so far :

public class EncryptActivity extends Activity {

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
 Bitmap thumbnail = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_encrypt);
}
public void Selimg(){
       Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                      startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

   }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     

     if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){

         Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

}
}

Comment: This question needs a lot of work. Do you have difficulty accessing a gallery when you click that button? Steganography deals with hiding a message into a carrier medium, but what method do you have in mind? LSB substitution? Embedding in the DCT coefficients of the image? Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried so far and what is the relevant code to your problem? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to construct a useful and clear question.

Comment: I have made this class. The function Selimg() is called by a button. I want this to open the gallery and store the image into 'thumbnail'.

Comment: `Selimg` is mostly empty. What is it exactly that you're asking? You're still stating what you want to do, but not what you have difficulty with. The only question stated so far in your post is how to get the message encrypted into the image, but this isn't very specific.

Comment: how do i make a function that goes to the gallery to select an image?

Comment: Are you looking for `FolderBrowseDialog` or `OpenFileDialog`? You should edit your question to clearly state what you can't work out and keep only any relevant code in it.